# In a course there's 10 boys and 10 girls and we need to divide them into 3 different groups..

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

We have $3$ groups $A,B,C$. 
We have to divide all the boys and the girls into these three groups such that in group $C$, there's exactly $6$ or $7$ members, there's atleast one girl, and the number of the boys must be greater than the number of girls. 
in how many ways we can do that? 

My attempt: I'm trying to split this problem into cases: 
Case 1: in group $C$ theres $5$ boys and $1$ girl, or $6$ boys and $1$ girl. for the rest of the boys and girls I would have to choose a group for each one from $A,B$ so we get $2^{14}+2^{13}$. 
Case 2: in group $C$ theres $4$ boys and $2$ girls or $5$ boys and $2$ girls. so $2^{14}+2^{13}$. 
Case 3: in group $C$ theres $4$ boys and $3$ girls: $2^{13}$. 
Then I summed up all the results and got $57344$ ways and the answer was $50610$. 
What am I missing? 
Appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the question is only about the possible combinations for group $C$.

This is where the answer 50610 comes from:

$$\binom{10}{5}\cdot\binom{10}{1} + \binom{10}{6}\cdot\binom{10}{1} + \binom{10}{4}\cdot\binom{10}{2} + \binom{10}{5}\cdot\binom{10}{2} + \binom{10}{4}\cdot\binom{10}{3} = 50610$$

For example: to choose 5 boys (out of 10) and 1 girl (out of 10) to put into group $C$ we have $\binom{10}{5}\cdot\binom{10}{1}$ possibilities.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I really appreciate the help, but could you please like explain to me (intuitively) why my approach was wrong? I think I understood your answer but I wanna track my problem to the root and understand why what I did was wrong and why it's only combinations of group $C$.

Comment: @Pwaol why it's only combinations of group C? Because if you also consider the possibilities of how to assign the other  groups, the answer would be much larger than 50610 ...

Comment: And even if you do count them, you would still need to consider the ways of choosing the people in group $C$. So for example, you would have $\binom{10}{5}\cdot\binom{10}{1}\cdot 2^{14}$ ways if C should have 5 boys and 1 girl

Comment: Thanks alot :).